# Is this possible to call in encrypted way in Sinch Calling

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am using Sinch SDK for developing a android app which has audio & video call functionality. Is it possible to calling in encrypted way? I mean in audio call the audio stream send in encrypted format.

Answer (score 0):

The audio and video streams are transport encrypted via SRTP default. (like https)

Comment: can You share any video calling demo application?

Comment: When you download the sdk there is samples in there